# cryptsetup: "Walting for encrypted source device" when removing disk from RAID1

Tags: debian, boot, luks, cryptsetup

I'm under Debian 12 bookworm. Partition layout is as follows:
sdX1 (EFI files)
sdX2 (boot, md-raid1)
sdX3 (root, dm-crypt, luks, md-raid1)

As soon as i remove one of the disks and try to boot from a single drive, i get the message "cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device UUID-XXX" until it drops to initramfs. does not matter which drive i remove. how do i fix this?

Comment: Is the `X` the same in all the cases? If so there is no point whatsoever having RAID1 across two partitions on the same disk. It it's not please edit your question to clarify the actual layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `nofail` option to your `/etc/crypttab`, without it the missing LUKS device will be considered a critical error during boot.

From [crypttab man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crypttab.5.html):

> **nofail**
>
> This device will not be a hard dependency of cryptsetup.target. It'll still be pulled in and started, but the system will
> not wait for the device to show up and be unlocked, and boot will not fail if this is unsuccessful. Note that other units
> that depend on the unlocked device may still fail. In particular, if the device is used for a mount point, the mount point
> itself also needs to have the nofail option, or the boot will fail if the device is not unlocked successfully.

Comment: cryptsetup: WARNING: md126_crypt: ignoring unknown option 'nofail'.  
seems that this option is not available anymore.  
adding BOOT_DEGRADED=true to /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/mdadm did not help either